# Is there an ESLint rule to ensure safe access of object properties?

Tags: javascript, json, eslint

I have a JavaScript app with data coming in in JSON format.  The data contains deeply nested objects.

We have had bugs where deep object properties were attempted to be read and errored out.  I would like a lint rule that ensures all reads of object properties are guarded.

Example of code to allow:

```
const reward = data && data.activity && data.activity.reward;
// or
const reward = data?.activity?.reward;
```

Example of code to disallow:

```
const reward = data.activity.reward;
```

Is this lintable?

Comment: Personally, I'd highly recommend using TypeScript instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance TypeScript is a compile time type checker. The above is a runtime data scenario.

Comment: Linting is a compile-time checker too.

Comment: Right but the 'guard' operation applies at runtime.

Comment: @michaeljsalo Using optional chaining everywhere will not work either, it will just cause different errors in other locations that will be harder to track. You need them only for accessing the JSON data, not for every singe property access in your code. To distinguish this properly, you need TypeScript.